# In Text box user cannot enter 15 digits continuously, mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

We have scenario where user cannot entered 15 continue numeric digits(i.e 411111111111111) in text box, so we have validate it using data annotations in mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `[ReqularExpression]` attribute which will give both client and server side validation

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((?!\d{15}).)*$)", ErrorMessage = "The value cannot contain 15 or more consecutive digits")]
public string YourProperty { get; set; }
```

The negative lookahead - `(?!\d{15})` - specifies that if there are 15 (or more) consecutive digits, the match is discarded and its invalid.

Refer [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3m0im) for a more detailed description of the regex and some test cases (using 3 digits for simplicity).

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox isn't multiline, try setting its MaxLength property:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" MaxLength="15"></asp:TextBox>
```

Edit: Since your maxlength is 50 and you want to check if 15 continued numeric digits have been entered, you could try with the 'keypress' event:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function () { 
        $("#<%=tb1.ClientID %>").keypress(function () { 
            /* check here if the textbox' data is valid */
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

That won't help you with copy/paste actions though

Comment: actually user can enter max 50 characters, but the validation only if entered continues 15 numeric digits

Comment: I misunderstood, sorry. I guess it's a job for the 'keypress' event